# App for mapping WiFi strength?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ios

I am looking for an iOS app that allows me to record a log of both my home and office wireless networks strength.

- Ability to export to a format like CSV, KML or GPX
- Can filter to just the network the device is connected to (as opposed to all networks in the area)

I saw a great app for Windows called [inSSIDer](http://www.inssider.com/) but don't have a laptop and would prefer to get a large log from just roaming around my office/home and then do some analysis of the log after a few days of collecting data.  Has anyone seen such an app?

[image]

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: 5.5 years and 15 questions, you should take 5 minute, to read our help center to avoid questions like this

Comment: Fair call. Please delete Q. Daniel did provide me the answer I need, so not sure if he loses points if Q is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general iOS is not capable of network scanning because of limitations built into the software.

- apps cannot keep using the network in background.
- apps are limited in how much location info they can get in the background.
- apps themselves are limited in working in the background at all.
- apps can only see a subset of wifi network info through the official API.

So an app could theoretically search for networks if you open it up but you wouldn't get much info on signal strength and location and even less when the app is working in the background.

An app could write to a file while it is open but I am not sure if it could do so in the background.

If you want useful network scanning info you will have to use a laptop, or a phone that has less restrictions like Android.